# What are locally parallelizable manifolds?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, symmetric-spaces

I came across this concept on this wiki page regarding [killing vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field). The last sentence in section "Cartan Involution" says that "Equivalently, the curvature tensor is covariantly constant on locally symmetric spaces, and so these are locally parallelizable; this is the [Cartan–Ambrose–Hicks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Ambrose%E2%80%93Hicks_theorem)."

I'm really confused that apparently every manifold is "locally parallelizable", since you simply take a local chart and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ automatically form a local parallelization. Therefore, I think it actually says that the manifold admits $n$ linearly independent local **killing** vector fields, not some general vector fields.

However, the wiki page doesn't cite anything here, so I don't know where that result come from, and of course I don't know how to prove it either. Besides, I don't understand its connection with Cartan–Ambrose–Hicks theorem.

Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: I never heard of this terminology: Anybody can edit Wikipedia articles, so I suggest you simply ignore this sentence. However, do read about the Cartan–Ambrose–Hicks theorem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So does that conjecture make sense? There locally exists a parallelization of killing vector fields?

Comment: If you mean a local parallelization by Killing fields, then it is not even a conjecture but a fact and it holds for all locally homogeneous Riemannian manifolds. However, this is not what the C-A-H theorem says. I checked on the Wikipedia page who is responsible for the offending sentence: It appears to be a physicist, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:67.198.37.16.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! Would you minding giving some references about the fact on the local parallelization by killing fields for all locally homogeneous Riemanniann manifolds? I'm still learning these things.

Comment: I will write a proof in a day or so.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that each locally symmetric space is locally homogeneous, and, since the question is local, I will limit myself to the discussion of homogeneous Riemannian manifolds. Namely, given a homogeneouse manifold $M$ and a point $x\in M$, I will construct a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a collection of Killing fields on $M$ whose restriction to $U$ defines a parallelization of $U$.

The condition that a Riemannian manifold $M$ is homogeneous is equivalent to the assumption that this manifold is of the form $G/H$, where $G$ is a Lie group, $H< G$ is a compact Lie subgroup and $G$ is equipped with a left-$G$-invariant Riemannian metric. Since $M$ is homogeneous, this identification can be made so that $x\in M$ corresponds to the projection of the identity element $e\in G$.  (The diffeomorphism $G/H\to M$ comes from the orbit map $g\mapsto gx, g\in G$.)

Now, given this description, let ${\mathfrak h}\subset {\mathfrak g}$ denote the Lie algebras of $H$ and $G$ respectively. Take **any** linear subspace ${\mathfrak p}\subset {\mathfrak g}$ such that we have a direct sum decomposition
$$
{\mathfrak g}= {\mathfrak h}\oplus {\mathfrak p}. 
$$
In particular, the dimension $d$ of ${\mathfrak p}$ is the same as the dimension of $M$. Taking a basis  $v_1,...,v_d$ in ${\mathfrak p}$, we see that these vectors project to Killing fields $X_1,...,X_d$ on $M$ which are linearly independent at $x$. By continuity, the same linear independence will hold  at all points in a sufficiently small neighborhood $U$ of $x$ thereby, providing a "Killing" parallelization of $U$.

According to the comments, this observation appears to answer your actual question. Needless to say, this is **not** what the Cartan–Ambrose–Hicks theorem says. Looking at the record of a person who made the edit in the Wikipedia page claiming that "this is the Cartan–Ambrose–Hicks theorem," this person is likely to be a physicist and the quote should not be taken seriously. This is also a general remark regarding Wikipedia articles: Anybody can edit these and, while, in general, the quality of math Wikipedia articles is quite good, occasionally what's written is wrong or misleading or unclear. *Reading Wikipedia is not a substitute to reading math books.*

Comment: As I remember, there are manifolds where each killing vector field must have a zero. So they can't be linearly independent everywhere, i.e., not a parallelization. The projection from $\mathfrak{p}$ only implies that they are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent, not $C^\infty$-linearly independent.

Comment: @Selene: You are right, the statement should be local. I will correct the answer accordingly.